# TextUtil does not get the exact value

Tags: java, android

I'm having problem getting the exact value of my edit ext. The logic is if the edit text is empty, assigned a value, then if it is not empty use the inputted value. When I input value on all edit ext it is getting the real value vice versa if it's empty it displays zero. My problem is when I enter one value or two, it doesn't give me the actual value instead it displays zero. which is not valid.

Here's my code:

```
String value = salary.getText().toString(); 
String ot = overtimePay.getText().toString();
String hp = holidayPay.getText().toString();
String nd = nightDiff.getText().toString();                   
String allowance = allowances.getText().toString();

float f_salary;
float f_ot;
float f_hp;
float f_nd;
float f_allowance;

f_salary = Float.parseFloat(value);




if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
    if((!TextUtils.isEmpty(ot)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(hp)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nd)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(allowance))) {
        f_ot = Float.parseFloat(ot);
        f_hp = Float.parseFloat(hp);
        f_nd = Float.parseFloat(nd);
        f_allowance = Float.parseFloat(allowance);                  
    } else {                            
        f_ot = 0;
        f_hp = 0;
        f_nd = 0;
        f_allowance = 0;
    }

   Log.d("f_salary", String.valueOf(f_salary));
   Log.d("f_ot", String.valueOf(f_ot));
   Log.d("f_hp", String.valueOf(f_hp));
   Log.d("f_nd", String.valueOf(f_nd));
   Log.d("f_allowance", String.valueOf(f_allowance));
}
```

Comment: but according to `(!TextUtils.isEmpty(ot)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(hp)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(nd)) && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(allowance))` it will always give zero, unless you fill all fields

Comment: what should i do, if for instance,  i want to input a value to a 2 edittext only out of 4 edittext. like i input f_ot = 45, f_allowance =  9, when i check it on logcat, it gives me 0 to all.

Comment: think about conditions you set and how to handle all the possible cases you need

Comment: i tried changing the logic && to || but it gives me this error java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float: ""